# Open azure web app URL in new tab with the post data as headers

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have azure web app which I want to open in new tab with post data as headers .
I have used below code using JavaScript which successfully open the azure web URL but having error as "**The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used**" and the different thing is that When I refresh the page it opens

```
$scope.openurl= function {
const URL = 'https://xyz.azurewebsites.net';
                const _data = {
                    token: "54165165165"
                };
                submit_post_via_hidden_form(URL, _data);
        };

        function submit_post_via_hidden_form(url, params) {
            var f = $("<form target='_blank' method='post' style='display:none;' id='form1'></form>").attr({
                action: url
            }).appendTo(document.body);

            for (var i in params) {
                if (params.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    $('<input type="hidden" />').attr({
                        name: i,
                        value: params[i]
                    }).appendTo(f);
                }
            }

            f.submit();

            f.remove();
        }
```

Comment: If the back-end language of the website is not .net core 3.1, the solution idea is the same, I hope to inspire you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Due to your project without server-side code. I suggest you put your data into `localstorage`, when open the page you can use them `$(document).ready(function(){ ###read data here from localstorgae### })`.

**PRIVIOUS**

Based on your description, I know the cause of the problem. First of all, because you send post request to open a web page and transfer data through the form body. Then your backend program needs to process this request.

The solution is as follows. You can download [my demo](https://github.com/Jason446620/TransDataByWinOpen). (.Net Core 3.1)

*Startup.cs*

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        // Enable AllowSynchronousIO 
        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
        });
    }
```

*HomeController.cs*

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body);
        string body = stream.ReadToEnd();
        ViewData["id2"] = body;
        return View();
    }
```

*Index.cshtml*

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
    <p>Test Data</p>
    <p>@ViewData["id2"]</p>
</div>
```

And you also need add a class in project.

*ReadableBodyStreamAttribute.cs*

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
// For ASP.NET 3.1
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace defaultPost
{
    public class ReadableBodyStreamAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            // For ASP.NET 3.1
            context.HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
        }
    }
}
```

*Mytest.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        const URL = 'https://panshubeiweb.azurewebsites.net/';
                const _data = {
                    token: "54165165165"
                };
                openPostWindow(URL, _data);
    })

    function openPostWindow(url, params) {

      var newWin = window.open(),
            formStr = '';
       formStr = '<form style="visibility:hidden;" method="POST" action="' + url + '">' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="params" id="form2" value="' + params + '" />' +
        '</form>';
     newWin.document.body.innerHTML = formStr;
     newWin.document.forms[0].submit();

     return newWin;
  }
</script>
<body>  
</body>
</html>
```

[My demo](https://github.com/Jason446620/TransDataByWinOpen) you can download from github and test it. You also need to serialize the body string (`string body = stream.ReadToEnd();`) according to the business.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason.
Yes I think this might be the reason.
I have azure web app as pure HTML,JS and CSS project .
Is there any alternative for the answer you have given for the HTML Project

Comment: @Jumbo Since your project has no server-side code, it is not possible to pass data through the form and open the page through `window.open`. My personal suggestion is to store the required data in the `localstorage` and determine whether the data exists when opening the page, and then destroy it after use.

Comment: localstorage does not work if the URL is different ,The new tab is opened with the different URL

Comment: Can you try to use cache in browser?

Comment: I have search about Cache ,but Cache does not work in IE :( 
Can you suggest me any other idea !!!

Comment: Tried with Cookie does not work with cross origin (different URL)

Comment: Can you consider basing your static website on .net framework? Only a few configurations need to be modified to complete the migration of the static website, which is also convenient for future expansion. Suggestions can be considered, because there is no support for back-end services, many functions are limited.

Comment: `<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>`

Comment: You can consider that the time spent will not take up too much. I sincerely hope you can deal with your problem quickly.